# How to update git flow release branch name to reflect minor version increase?

Tags: git, git-flow

Lets say I started release using:

> git flow release start 1.5.0

Then I published the release branch as part of CI/CD for bitbucket pipelines to build this release for testing team:

> git flow release publish 1.5.0

Then I made a fix to a bug on this branch, but have not committed it yet. I feel like the version must be something like 1.5.1. Not necessarily, but even internally it would be nice to know that bug found in 1.5.0 have been closed in 1.5.1.

How do I update version to 1.5.1 using git flow? (I know how to create branches using plain git commands, but I am trying to use git flow technique). Or am I trying to use git flow the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The branch name doesn't actually matter, so you don't have to change it. Merging the release branch into `master` (or `main`) is what signifies a deployment to production, and it doesn't matter if you have multiple builds (typically tagged) on the same release branch.

**Side Note**: at my company in a repo that uses Git Flow we recently stopped making numbered release branches and now we have one long lived release branch. (It simply goes dormant temporarily between releases.) The main reason for this was so we didn't have to setup security on the branch every time we created a new branch name.

**Side Side Note**: in my experience, the Git Flow *commands* aren't useful enough to warrant using them (or at least using them exclusively). I'd prefer all team members learn the normal Git commands, and we try to document them clearly. This is especially because many of our developers also use  other repos that are on different branching strategies.